# Compute distribution in Hidden Markov models

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, hidden-markov-models

Let Z1, Z2, ..., Zn be the latent variables, and X1, X2, ... Xn be the observed ones in a hidden markov models.

Let's assume that the parameters of the hidden Markov models are known:
the initial distribution π (zi), the transition matrix T, and the probability density function P(Xi|Zi) (Let's assume this distribution is a Gaussian distribution).

I can use forward algorithm to compute the probability p(Xk|X1, ..., Xk-1) = p(X1, ... Xk)/p(X1, ..., Xk-1)

My question is how can I compute the distribution of P(Xk|X1, ..., Xk-1)? (Is this distribution is Gaussian?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The distributions in an HMM factor. Thus p(X_k|X_1...X_k-1) is a product:

p(X_k|X_1...X_k-1) = \sum_Z p(Z_k|Z_k-1) p(X_k|Z_k)

If p(X_k|Z_k) is Gaussian, then p(X_k|X_1...X_k-1) is a mixture of Gaussians with mixture weights given by p(Z_k|Z_k-1)